# MonoTouch project leads to Application Loader error message "icon dimensions (0 x 0) don't meet the size requirements"

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, icons, application-loader

I compiled a iOS app on MonoTouch for distribution. Now I try to get it on the App Store with the Application Loader. But I get an error message "...icon dimensions (0 x 0) don't meet the size requirements...".

On this forum I found other developers which had the same problem with XCode. Their solution was to disable the compression for png files. But how can I do this in MonoTouch?

Does anyone know about this problem?

Comment: Yeah, i have solved the Problem! I found out taht the Application Loader I used was not the newest one. So I downloaded the newest version (2.5.1) from iTunes Connect and now it works fine!

Comment: Glad you solved it! If you have enough reputation points (I don't recall how many are required) then move your comment into an answer and mark the question as answered (so other people searching will see an answer is available). Note that it's ok on stackoverflow.com to answer your own question.

Comment: I had the same problem yesterday, and it was even failing on the exact same build I upload a couple weeks ago.

Answer (score 3):

Jörn resolved his issue but here are the full steps for others.

The error:

> icon dimensions (0x0) don't meet the size requirements

is the result of an Xcode bug with validating app icons that occurs in OS X 10.7.3. I have heard the issue occurs also after an OS X 10.6.8 security patch.

To work around this issue, download and install the latest version of Application Loader (2.5.1) and reattempt your submission.

The latest Application Loader is available from [iTunes Connect](http://itunesconnect.apple.com) > "Manage Applications" > "Download Application Loader" link at the bottom.

Installing the latest App Loader fixes the problem in Xcode because it uses App Loader under the covers to submit Application Archives in the Organizer.